# How to replace specific string in the list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote down the code to generate ['---', '---', '---'] below:

```
ans = []
for i in range(top, bottom):
    ans.append("-"*3)
```

If I would like to change first '-' in the first string and last '-' in the last string into '*', how to complete code below? :)

desired output would be:

```
['*--', '---', '--*']
```

by adding lines below the code.

Comment: what's `right` and `left`

Comment: @aws_apprentice Sorry I edited the code.

Comment: please edit your answer with expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add only the first and last caracter of each string you need to use a loop in a loop:

```
ans = []
for i in range(top, bottom):
    line = []
    for j in range(right-left):
        char = '-'
        if (i == 0 and j == 0) or (i == bottom - 1 and j == (right-left) -1):
            char = '*'
        line += char
    ans.append(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to replace only first and last strings in list, that means you have to constraint your loop to avoid those end conditions and treat them differently:

```
ans = []

ans.append('*' + '-'*(3-1))
for _ in range(top+1, bottom-1):
    ans.append("-"*(3))
ans.append('-'*(3-1) + '*')

print(ans)
# ['*--', '---', '--*']
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you only want to have the start and end cases different, I think it's easiest to simply handle these special cases with an if-statement.

Example:

```
start = 0
end = 3

ans = []
for i in range(start, end):
    if i == start:
        ans.append("*" + "-" * 2)
    elif i == end-1:
        ans.append("-" * 2 + "*")
    else:
        ans.append("-" * 3)

print(ans)
```

Remember to subtract 1 from `end` when performing the check since `range()` is exclusive (the second argument of `range` is not included in the returned list).

Result:

```
['*--', '---', '--*']
```

An alternative to nested if-else-if statements I personally find more readable is:

```
start = 0
end = 3

ans = []
for i in range(start, end):
    if i == start:
        ans.append("*" + "-" * 2)
        continue
    if i == end-1:
        ans.append("-" * 2 + "*")
        continue

    ans.append("-" * 3)

print(ans)
```